# How to add range in multiple columns for countif formula?

Tags: worksheet-function, countif

I have a sheet where I want to count in multiple columns if it meets a single criteria. I am running into issue where if I select multiple columns under Range, it considers it a Criteria after first column selection-

Current formula is -

```
=COUNTIF($J$8:$J$14,"US")
```

Formula that works is this but is very tedious as I have more than 50 ranges to select-

```
=COUNTIFS(D8:D9,"IT")+COUNTIF(J8:J9,"IT")+COUNTIF(V8:V9,"IT")
```

[image]

Any simpler formula where I can just select range in multiple columns with same criteria?

[image]

Comment: why not just: `=COUNTIFS(D8:V9,"IT")`?

Comment: Because it does not have to be applied on all columns and rows, only specific cells like D8:D9,D17:D18,J8:J9,J17:J18,P8:P9,P17:P18

Comment: But will `IT` show in any other column that should not be counted?

Comment: Yes it does. In screenshot, "IT" could appear under Allocated OR Interim OR Missing. I need to get a total of IT in Allocated, Interim and Missing each.

If I apply entire range like D8:V9, I would not know where IT appeared, under Allocated, interim or missing.

Comment: AH, then use OFFSET(): `=COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$8:$D$9,,(ROW(1:50)-1)*6),"IT")`

Comment: sorry the row numbers need to be absolute: `=COUNTIF(OFFSET($D$8:$D$9,,(ROW($1:$50)-1)*6),"IT")`

Answer (score 1):

From the question and the comments, it seems like you want to get a total count of how many times `IT` appears in all of the columns to the right of those with `Allocated` in row 7. I.E., your data comes in sets of two columns. One entry is `Allocated` and `Region`, the next is `Interim` and `Region`, etc. If that is correct, then something like this can solve it for a region of any size:

```
=LET(allData,C8:T9,prevHeader,OFFSET(allData,-1,-1,1),targetData,FILTER(allData,prevHeader="Allocated"),SUM(IF(targetData="IT",1,0)))
```

This relies on the [`LET()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) and [`FILTER()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) functions so, if your version of Excel doesn't have those, this won't work. There's an alternative version of the formula at the bottom of this answer that should work, though. The `LET()` function lets you rename complicated formulas to a single variable for easier reference later. We can breakdown the big formula above into these easier to understand bits:

- `allData,C8:T9` saves all of your data (not including the headers) as the variable `allData`.
- `prevHeader,OFFSET(allData,-1,-1,1)` offsets from the data by going up one row, to the left one column, and then only being 1 row tall.
- `targetData,FILTER(allData,prevHeader="Allocated")` returns all the cells from `allData` where the header of the column to the left is "Allocated". This will be all the data form the "Region" columns that are just after the "Allocated" columns.
- `SUM(IF(targetData="IT",1,0))` turns all the "IT" values to 1s, everything else to 0s, and then adds them up. `COUNTIF()` doesn't work because of how we're using [spill functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531). This is the last argument so it doesn't get matched up with a variable name, it just gets returned as the result.

---

The nice part about all this is that it's very easy to build a little table, reference the row and column headers of that little table, and then make one formula that fills in all the data:

[image: TableOption1]

The formula in `W8` is:

```
=LET(allData,$C$8:$T$9,prevHeader,OFFSET(allData,-1,-1,1),targetData,FILTER(allData,prevHeader=W$7),SUM(IF(targetData=$V8,1,0)))
```

Note that we have to set some of those range references as absolute (`$`) instead of relative, but not all of them. That lets us copy / paste that formula over our nice little table and everything updates as needed.

---

**If you don't have LET() and FILTER()**

You can drop all the fancy bits and write this much shorter but, IMHO, more difficult to follow formula:

```
=SUM(IF(IF(OFFSET(C8:T9,-1,-1,1)="Allocated",C8:T9,0)="IT",1,0))
```

That formula was created by taken the original formula at the top of this answer and substituting the renamed bits back into the formula bit by bit. We also had to exchange a `FILTER()` for a `IF(~,1,0)`. You can make this into a pretty table, too, just like above. The formula would instead be:

```
=SUM(IF(IF(OFFSET($C$8:$T$9,-1,-1,1)=W$7,$C$8:$T$9,0)=$V8,1,0))
```

Comment: Seems to be working for most part. How do I use this first formula with LET() and FILTER() when I want to select rows that are not continuous, i.e select rows 11:14,19 and 23 to be counted?

Comment: @Paul Is there some indicator of which rows you want to count? IE, all those rows will have some value in a column to the left that wasn't included in your screenshot?

Comment: Yes all columns to the left will either have 1 or 0 in allocated, interim or Missing. And region will have US, IT etc. 

Added another screenshot - 
With regards to rows - I want various counts - 1 for counts in pink i.e Row 8,9. 1 for blues i.e rows 10,17,18, 1 for green i.e rows 11-14, 19 etc

Comment: @Paul That's a more complicated question and different than what was originally asked. I'd recommend asking a new question. You know how to pick certain columns. How can you filter for rows of only a certain color? There are [ways to get a cell's color](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-formula-based-on-cell-color/) but not inside a formula within a cell. I setup the sheet [a little differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkyva.png) and I updated the two formulas to be what's shown in the next comment. Any additional explanation should be in a new question.

Comment: @Paul `=LET(allData,$C$8:$T$9,prevHeader,OFFSET(allData,-1,-1,1),colorColumn,OFFSET(allData,0,-2,,1),targetData,FILTER(FILTER(allData,prevHeader=W$7),colorColumn=$U8),SUM(IF(targetData="IT",1,0)))` or `=SUM(IF(IF($A$8:$A$9=$U8,IF(OFFSET($C$8:$T$9,-1,-1,1)=W$7,$C$8:$T$9,0),0)="IT",1,0))`

Comment: Can't I just use your previous formula of =LET(allData,$C$8:$T$9,prevHeader,OFFSET(allData,-1,-1,1),targetData,FILTER(allData,prevHeader=W$7),SUM(IF(targetData=$V8,1,0)))  and repeat it for multiple rows like above formula + same formula + same formula etc just by changing rows in subsequent formulas?

Comment: @Paul Yes, that would work but you're back to manually setting all the row references.